# снипеты ES6 import

Tags: дефект, сниппеты

### T1

```js
console.log('c')
```

```html
<script type="module">
console.log('a')
</script>

<script>
console.log('b')
</script>
```

### T2 - демо в реальном применении

```js
console.log(!!window['$'], '$', 'JavaScript')
```

```html
<script type="module"> // umdLibLoader.js
  import 'https://unpkg.com/jquery'
</script>

<script type="module">
console.log(!!window['$'], '$', 'script type="module"')
</script>

<script>
console.log(!!window['$'], '$', 'script')
</script>
```

### ожидаемое поведение

код в блоке `language: lang-js` будет работать как в `script type="module"`

### предлагаю

добавить "галочку" `type="module"` для блока `language: lang-js`

### доводы ЗА ввод "галочки"

1. это удобно, логично, ... .
2. скоро должны "подвезти" top level `await` ...

   - https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await

     > Status: Stage 3

Comment: И с чего бы им быть модулями?

Comment: ок, перефразирую: нам необходимо добавить галочку `type="module"` для блока `language: lang-js`

Comment: Это ж сниппеты, зачем в них модули? А top-level await можно сымитировать и без модулей, просто добавив галочку заворачивания кода в async-функцию